# How to deal with asynchronous problems in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display data stored in ch ! But my problem is that ch is displayed before the data is stored !
I think this is an Asynchronous Problems! How can I solve this problem.
When I try to get length of ch, I get always 0. Even if I store data statically in ch, I get the length 0.
I think this is an Asynchronous Problems! How can I solve this problem.

function RechercheFiltrée() {

```
var nom = document.getElementById('nompre').value;
var matricule = document.getElementById('matcle').value;

$.ajax({
    url: "myWebServiceURL",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      var stock = [];
      $(xml).find('Population').each(function() {
          var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
          $(this).find("directories").each(function() 
            {
              dossier = $(this).attr('dossier');
              stock.push(dossier);
            });
          });

    var ch = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < stock.length; i++) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/mySecondWebServiceURL" + stock[i],
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
          var NMPRES = "";
          var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xml2json(xml, ""));
          var nom = jsonObj.SubmitResponse.occurrences.occurrence.filter(x => x["@datasection"] === "TS")[0].data.filter(x => x.item === "NMPRES")[0].value;
          var matcle = jsonObj.SubmitResponse.occurrences.occurrence.filter(function(x) {
            return x["@datasection"] === "LM"
          })[0].data.filter(x => x.item === "MATCLE")[0].value;

          var dossier = jsonObj.SubmitResponse.occurrences.occurrence.filter(function(x) {
            return x["@datasection"] === "LM"
          })[0]["@dossier"];

          ch.push({
            "nom": nom,
            "matcle": matcle,
            "dossier": dossier
          });
          if ($('#population').val() != null && firstIter == false) {

          }
        },
        error: function(request, error) {
          console.log('error Connexion : ' + error + ' request Connexion : ' + request);
        }
      });
    }

    var txt = "";
    var firstIter = true;

    for (var key in ch) {
      if (ch[key].matcle === matricule) {
        txt += "<option  value='" + ch[key].dossier + "'" + firstSelect(firstIter) + ">" + ch[key].nom + "</option>";

        firstIter = false;
      }
    }
    $('#population').html(txt)
  },
  error: function(request, error) {
    console.log('error Connexion : ' + error + ' request Connexion : ' + request);
  }
});

}
```

Comment: There are some errors in your code, like extra commas and curly brackets. Check your syntax to make sure it is not a simple syntax error first.

Comment: Of these syntax errors, there's one in particular that stands out...yet I'm not sure it really is...`RechercheFiltrée(` Note the different colors of black and blue at:`ée`. Just to be safe, try using `ee` instead.

Comment: @LambdaNinja I have edited !

Comment: Not exactly what I meant, because the formatting of the editor wasn't the problem, it's the fact that an identifier has an accented character to which I've never seen before which gives me pause to ponder...if there is a character not readily available on a keystroke, would that char be a reasonable for an identifier. In other words, if another programmer were to have to work on that code and does not speak French. Does that unfortunate programmer need to cut and paste or use key combos just use that identifier?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not waiting for the second service to respond.
It should be something like this:

```
const deferreds = stock.map((stockItem) => {
   //... your logic with ch.push here
   return $.ajax({
      // your call to the second service
   });
});

$.when(...deferreds).then(() => {
   // your code 
   // for (var key in ch) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I'd rather take is to break the code down and use Promises. You really should take your time to learn Promises. It's a JavaScript standard and what jQuery uses under the hood.

```
function RechercheFiltrée() {
  var nom = document.getElementById('nompre').value;
  var matricule = document.getElementById('matcle').value;

  return $.ajax({
      url: "myWebServiceURL",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "xml"
  });
}

function getStockArray(xml) {
  var stocks = [];

  $(xml).find('Population').each(function() {
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      $(this).find("directories").each(function() {
        {
          dossier = $(this).attr('dossier');
          stocks.push(dossier);
        });
      });
  });

  return stocks;
}

function getStocks(stocks) {
  return Promise.all(stocks.map(fetchStock));
}

function fetchStock (stock) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/mySecondWebServiceURL" + stock,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml"
  })
  .then(formatStockInfo)
}

function formatStockInfo (xml) {
    var NMPRES = "";
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xml2json(xml, ""));
    var nom = jsonObj.SubmitResponse.occurrences.occurrence.filter(x => x["@datasection"] === "TS")[0].data.filter(x => x.item === "NMPRES")[0].value;
    var matcle = jsonObj.SubmitResponse.occurrences.occurrence.filter(function(x) {
      return x["@datasection"] === "LM"
    })[0].data.filter(x => x.item === "MATCLE")[0].value;

    var dossier = jsonObj.SubmitResponse.occurrences.occurrence.filter(function(x) {
      return x["@datasection"] === "LM"
    })[0]["@dossier"];

    if ($('#population').val() != null && firstIter == false) {

    }

    return {
      "nom": nom,
      "matcle": matcle,
      "dossier": dossier
    };    
}

function updateSelectMenu (ch) {
  var txt = "";
  var firstIter = true;

  for (var key in ch) {
    if (ch[key].matcle === matricule) {
      txt += "<option  value='" + ch[key].dossier + "'" + firstSelect(firstIter) + ">" + ch[key].nom + "</option>";

      firstIter = false;
    }
  }

  $('#population').html(txt)
}

RechercheFiltrée()
  .then(getStockArray)
  .then(getStocks)
  .done(updateSelectMenu);
```

Comment: Thnx for your reply but I still getting the same  problem ! this code call updateSelectMenu before formatStockInfo! So it loops in something undefined (ch) :/

Comment: "updateSelectMenu" will run only after "getStocks" returns, and "getStocks" will return only after "fetchStock" and "formatStockInfo" had ran for every stock in the array. This is how Promises work.